# Conditional Styling in Knockout

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, html, knockout.js

I am working on `Asp.Net MVC application` which retrieves data from a `SQL table` and displays it on the page using `knockout JS and Odata`. I would like to control the color of an item based on the user who logged into the application.

For Example, I have the following view:

```
table class="clientTable">

    <thead>

        <tr>
            <th>Company</th>
            <th>Grade</th>
            <th>Term</th>
            <th>Location</th>
            <th>Pipeline</th>  
        </tr>

    </thead>
<!--ko foreach: products-->

    <tr>
    <td data-bind="text: Company"></td>
    <td data-bind="text: Grade"></td>
    <td data-bind="text: Term"></td>
    <td data-bind="text: Location"></td>
    <td data-bind="text: Pipeline"></td>

 </tbody>
    <!--/ko-->
```

The above script just pulls the data from the table and puts it on the webpage in a html table. But I have every user assigned to a `Company` with its `Id` and I want the data associated with the `company` of the user in `RED`

I have following data in my Users Table

```
Id UserName CompanyId
1  demouser  1
```

And Company Table has following

```
Id Company
1  testComp
4   demo
```

Original data that has be displayed to the user if from table `testData` and it is as follows:

```
Id CompanyId Grade       Term Location Pipeline
1  1         book        Q1   USA      pipe
2  4         electronic  Q2   UK       pipe
```

The above data should be displayed on the webpage as follows when user `demouser` is logged in  is:

```
Company  Grade      Term Location Pipeline
testComp Book       Q1   USA      pipe    //This line should be in RED
demo     Electronic Q2   UK       pipe
```

I was able to pull all the data except displaying the `company` data associated with the user logged in using Knockout Js as follows

```
self.getverticaldata = function () {
        $.ajax({
            dataType: "json",
            url: '/odata/CC',
            data: ko.toJSON(self.products),
            async: false,
            success: function (data) {
                self.datainput((ko.utils.arrayMap(data.value, function (ccrd) {
                    var obsCCrude = {
                        Id: ccrd.Id,
                        CompanyId: ccrd.CompanyId,
                        Grade: ko.observable(ccrd.Grade),
                        Term: ko.observable(ccrd.Term),
                        Product: ccrd.Product,
                        Location: ko.observable(ccrd.Location),
                        Pipeline: ko.observable(ccrd.Pipeline),

                    }

                    return obsCCrude;
                })));
            }
        });
    }

    this.getverticaldata();
```

Is there a better way I could achieve this?

Comment: added knockout js script

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional formatting by using **[Knockout's Style Binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/style-binding.html)**.

Here's a simple example of it's usage where it is setting the font color to red for `id == 2`, otherwise it will be green:

```
<span data-bind="text: id, style: { color: id == 2 ? 'red' : 'green' }"></span>
```

You can put whatever logic you require in there.

**Here's working example:**

```js
var viewModel = function() {
  var self = this;

  self.users = ko.observableArray([{
    id: 1,
    company: 'Company x'
  }, {
    id: 2,
    company: 'Company y'
  }, {
    id: 3,
    company: 'Company z'
  }]);

};

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div data-bind="foreach: users">
  <p>
  <span data-bind="text: 'ID: ' + id, style: { color: id == 2 ? 'red' : 'green' }"></span><br>
  <span data-bind="text: 'CO: ' + company, style: { color: id == 2 ? 'red' : 'green' }"></span>
    </p>
<div>
```

Comment: Thanks but the above code seems like hardcoded company list but I want that to be pulled from the database based on the user who logged into to the application

Comment: @Dev that was just an example of how you can use conditional formatting. You would have to have some flag or value setup to power the conditional logic based on what you are trying to achieve. You would replace the `self.users` object with your array, returned from the server and use conditional logic on it's properties.